# Angular interating 2 different types of arrays - linear and json array in single ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a json which has array of string and array of json objects as shown in the code. Have to iterate it using ng-repeat and need to show the string value as it is, if the array is of strings and a specific key's value if the array is of json objects. Please Help!

```html
<html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js">
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div ng-init="data=[
              {'name':'Name1','filterValues':['eq1','eq2','eq3','eq4','eq5','eq6']},
              {'name':'Name2','filterValues':[{'id':'eid1','description':'Description 1'},{'id':'eid2','description':'Description 2'},{'id':'eid3','description':'Description 3'},{'id':'eid4','description':'Description 4'},{'id':'eid5','description':'Description 5'}]}
              ]">
       <div data-ng-repeat="d1 in data" >{{d1.name}}
          <div data-ng-repeat="d2 in d1.filterValues"> {{d2}}</div>
        </div>

<span style="color:tomato">"Here, under Name2, I need only the Description Values" </span>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether the iterated element has an id property or not. Based on that display `d2.description` or `d2`. It can be done with  `?` conditional operator as below.

`{{d2.id?d2.description:d2}}`

```html
<html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js">
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div ng-init="data=[
              {'name':'Name1','filterValues':['eq1','eq2','eq3','eq4','eq5','eq6']},
              {'name':'Name2','filterValues':[{'id':'eid1','description':'Description 1'},{'id':'eid2','description':'Description 2'},{'id':'eid3','description':'Description 3'},{'id':'eid4','description':'Description 4'},{'id':'eid5','description':'Description 5'}]}
              ]">
       <div data-ng-repeat="d1 in data" >{{d1.name}}
          <div data-ng-repeat="d2 in d1.filterValues"> {{d2.id?d2.description:d2}}</div>
        </div>

<span style="color:tomato">"Here, under Name2, I need only the Description Values" </span>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tintu C Raju